# How to scale option pricing components in regard to time

Tags: option-pricing, interest-rates, models, variance

I am looking at closed-form options approximations, in particular the [Bjerksund-Stensland model](http://old.nhh.no/for/dp/2002/0902.pdf).

I have run into a very basic question. How should I scale the input variables in regard to time? My assumptions would be:

- r (riskless interest rate) should be an annual rate, so if the 3-month T-bill yields 0.03%, then I should use .12.
- σ (variance) should be annual (and according to [How to calculate future distribution of price using volatility?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-to-calculate-future-distribution-of-price-using-volatility/49#49), variance scales with the *square root* of time.
- T (time to expiration) should be in years, so expiration in 83 days would be 83/365 (=0.227397) years.
- b (cost of carry) should be an annual rate.

Have I got that right? Are there other input variables that I will need to scale before plugging in?

Comment: Your T-bill yield quote is probably already annualized using a 360 day year. http://www.investopedia.com/articles/bonds/08/bond-yield-convention-conversion.asp

Comment: @user508, thank you for the correction. So when they discount my $1000 T-bill, I should expect to get 7 or 8 pennies each 3 months. (I'm glad it's electronically deposited, lest the postage exceed the check.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.
(use the same time unit for all of the parameters)