# Getting the actual distribution of a stock price at time T using implied volatility

Tags: implied-volatility, equities, distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to derive the implied probability distribution from B-S volatilities?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/how-to-derive-the-implied-probability-distribution-from-b-s-volatilities)

Let's assume a stock price S, with volatility $\sigma$ constant, no dividend, and risk free interest rate $r$ we have :

$ dS=\mu Sdt +\sigma SdW $

And therefore using ito's lemma we get that $\ln(S)$ follows the following normal distribution:

$ \ln(S) \rightarrow \phi((r -\frac {\sigma^2}2)T,\sigma \sqrt(T))  $

But in real life the volatility is not a constant, and he future volatility is actualy unknown.

Now using black scholes equation I can calculate the implied volatility and I use it as an approximation of the expected volatility in the future. The implied vol will depend on the maturity T and the strike K (the current stock price and r are known).

How can I get the actual distribution of S (or ln(S)) using the value implied volatility $\sigma(T,K)$ ? Or in another words, how does the volatility smile modify the expected distribution of S ?

Not sure my question is clear, If you need any more clarification tell me.

I read a question with a similar title but the actual question is different : [How to calculate future distribution of price using volatility?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-to-calculate-future-distribution-of-price-using-volatility)

Comment: Hi Ricky, welcome to quant.SE. I believe your question has been asked and answered, though not where you pointed. Check out the question above and, if your question differs, please specify how.

Comment: The question is answered here: [implied http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/how-to-derive-the-implied-probability-distribution-from-b-s-volatilities/1676#1676]

Comment: @BrianB Thx it perfectly answers my question.

Comment: @TalFishman Thx it perfectly answers my question.